# Sencha Touch 2 - conflict itemtap and itemswipe

Tags: extjs4, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am developing an app using Sencha Touch 2, and I have a screen to list a list of some records saved on the database. The user have the option to click and view detailed information about the record or swipe the line to show a delete button. My problem is that when I swipe the line, the itemtap event is fired. Do anyone have an idea to get around this?

Comment: Next time, tag your question with Sencha-Touch-2 if you want help on Sencha Touch 2

Comment: And show us your code, that would help us to help you

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that you will need to put both the event listeners together i.e. in your controller

```
downloadslist: {
    itemtap : 'showItem',
    itemswipe: 'deleteItem'
},
```

If you put it as

```
downloadslist: {
    itemtap : 'showItem'
},

downloadslist: {
    itemswipe: 'deleteItem'
},
```

It won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have someList ref in your controller, add this to control block:

`someList: {
     itemtap: 'onItemTap',
     itemswipe: 'onItemSwipe'
}`

then define two function-handlers as follow

    `onItemTap: function(item, index, target, record, e) {
        console.log('in onItemTap');
},
    onItemSwipe: function(this, index, target, record, e,) {
        console.log('in onItemSwipe');
}`

This should work.